# Was trying to install something using docker, noticed it was installing very large files, terminated it but a lot space has still been used up

Tags: apt, nvidia, bash, docker

I was trying to get this up and running -  https://github.com/SeanNaren/deepspeech.pytorch

However I noticed that it was pulling from the CUDA repo, which I don't want because my system does not support the latest CUDA, so I hit Ctrl+Z

The problem is that it has eaten up a massive chunk of my storage. I've gone from 17GB free to 5GB free and I have no idea where it downloaded whatever it downloaded.

```
sudo docker run -ti --gpus all -v `pwd`/data:/workspace/data --entrypoint=/bin/bash --net=host --ipc=host seannaren/deepspeech.pytorch:latest
Unable to find image 'seannaren/deepspeech.pytorch:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from seannaren/deepspeech.pytorch
7ddbc47eeb70: Pulling fs layer 
c1bbdc448b72: Pulling fs layer 
8c3b70e39044: Waiting 
45d437916d57: Pull complete 
d8f1569ddae6: Pull complete 
85386706b020: Pull complete 
ee9b457b77d0: Pull complete 
be4f3343ecd3: Pull complete 
30b4effda4fd: Downloading  237.5MB/820.8MB
b398e882f414: Downloading  123.8MB/532.4MB
4fe309685765: Download complete 
a3c2440ebe6c: Downloading  43.46MB/1.482GB
bfc2a6d829f9: Pulling fs layer 
56422aad0e75: Waiting 
d11ed40776c9: Waiting 
85aff3bb1d21: Waiting 
970b7ad668a0: Waiting 
0aebb4274faa: Waiting 
b37bab316d28: Pulling fs layer 
14cf466eb30a: Waiting 
465c6b5707fe: Waiting 
1081be559ff7: Pulling fs layer 
df77249ea094: Waiting 
fe18afe6b974: Pulling fs layer 
0fd5b62aca78: Waiting 
e27134e17a67: Pulling fs layer 
^Z
[6]+  Stopped                 sudo docker run -ti --gpus all -v `pwd`/data:/workspace/data --entrypoint=/bin/bash --net=host --ipc=host seannaren/deepspeech.pytorch:latest
```

That's the terminal output. How do I remove what it downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you canceled it while docker was pulling images.

You can check your local images with `docker images`, then delete what you don't want using `docker rmi [IMAGE ID]`.

You can also use the following commands to purge unused docker data:

- Remove all stopped containers: `docker container prune --force`
- Remove all unused images: `docker image prune --all --force`
- Remove all unused local volumes: `docker volume prune --force`

---

Other Docker resources may be left on your system (such as networks and build caches).

If you want a more aggressive Docker cleanup, you can make use of `docker system prune` to [remove all unused data](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/):

> ```
> $ docker system prune --all --volumes
> WARNING! This will remove:
>         - all stopped containers
>         - all networks not used by at least one container
>         - all volumes not used by at least one container
>         - all images without at least one container associated to them
>         - all build cache
> Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can completely purge docker images, containers, networks, building cache with below single command in terminal.

```
docker system prune
```

It doesn't remove docker volume. If you want to remove volume also, you can execute below command in terminal.

```
docker system prune -a --volumes
```